# Using setter method in second function react native hooks state change

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have 2 functions , function1() and function2()

```
   function2(){
    return(
<TextInput/>
)
}

export default function1(){
const [name,setName]=useState('')
return(
<View>
{function2}
</View>

}
```

I have some textinputs in the second function which i need to change the states(which are in the first function) when user inputs something. 
**How to handle this situation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a handler function as props and invoke it in the function2.

```
 function2(props){
    //wherever you get the input call
    props.handleTextInput(inputString)
    return(
        <TextInput/>
    )
}

export default function1(){
    const [name,setName]=useState('');

    const handleTextInput = (name) => {
        setName(name);
    }

    return(
        <View>
            <function2 handleTextInput = {this.handleTextInput} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first, you are not invoking `function2` so I don't really understand how it's working

```
<View>
{function2} // you are not invoking()
</View>
```

but anyhow if you are declare `Function2` with capital letter, you can render it as react component and send `setName` as prop

```
const Function2 = ({setName}) =>{
    return(
     <TextInput/>
   )
}

...

<View>
 <Function2 setName={setName} />
</View>
```

or still with function invoking and send arg

```
function2(setName){
    return(
     <TextInput/>
   )
}

...

<View>
{function2(setName)}
</View>
```